# RoR3 api documentation for all methods used in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in a controller i can use request and params methods.

i know each controller is inheriting from ActionController::Base.

however, i cannot find these 2 methods in the api documentation for ActionController::Base http://api.rubyonrails.org

where are these methods defined? it would be great to know ALL methods that i can use in a controller.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request and params in ActionController:Base are shortcuts to the ActionController::Request object and its parameters method. It isn't well-documented, but you can see that by looking at the code for ActionController::Base.

Knowing that, you can find the documentation for these methods here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Request.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the Rails 3 docs or the Rails 2 docs? I like to read the docs through this site: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0.beta.3_ruby-v1.9/

If you go to the root, it lets you set your version of rails and ruby, so you have the right doc stack, with a good search feature etc. Maybe that will help :)

Comment: im looking at the api documentation from the link above. is that one for version 3?

Comment: The link I sent, yes. The site itself will display whatever version you ask for. But it's a restful url - it's displaying rails 3.0.0 beta 3, and ruby 1.9